# Hibernate generate additional query in ManyToMany relation while no CascadeType.REMOVE is set

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-security

I have the entity `User`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    (...)
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = false)
    )
    private List<Role> roles;
}
```

and entity `Role` with simple `id` and `name` columns.

`User` and `Role` have **many-to-many** relation with join table `users_roles`.

I have created method to remove a user:

```
public void remove(long userId) {
    Session session = getSession();

    //NativeQuery joinTableQuery = session.createNativeQuery("DELETE FROM users_roles ur WHERE ur.user_id = :userId");
    //joinTableQuery.setParameter("userId", userId);
    //joinTableQuery.executeUpdate();

    Query userQuery = session.createQuery("DELETE FROM User u WHERE u.id = :userId");
    userQuery.setParameter("userId", userId);
    userQuery.executeUpdate();
}
```

I have commented out first NativeQuery on purpose to check what happens. And what is interesting now Hibernate generates two queries:

- Hibernate: **delete from users_roles where (user_id) in (select id from users where id=?)**
- Hibernate: **delete from users where id=?**

Question:

Why does Hibernate generate additional query on `users_roles` (join table) while my `User` entity has no `CascadeType.REMOVE` set on `@ManyToMany` relation? I thought I have to write it myself (commented part).

Answer (score 0):

Your `User` entity owns the [many-to-many association](https://thoughts-on-java.org/ultimate-guide-association-mappings-jpa-hibernate/) to the `Role` entity. When you remove a `User`, Hibernate automatically also removes all entries from the association table. But it doesn't cascade the remove operation to the `Role` entity.

You should never use `CascadeType.REMOVE` on a many-to-many association. If you remove an entity, Hibernate will remove all associated entities even if they are still referenced by other entities. I explained that in great detail [on my blog](https://thoughts-on-java.org/avoid-cascadetype-delete-many-assocations/).

If you would use `CascadeType.REMOVE` on your `roles` association and remove a `User`, Hibernate would remove all `Role` entities referenced by that `User`. It would do that even if there are other `User` entity objects that are associated with these `Role`s.